# Drag from spotlight

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, finder, spotlight

Is there any way that I could implement the functionality of being able to drag files and folders from spotlight to a finder window?

Comment: What do you mean by "implement the functionality"? Are you trying to write a program to do this or are you trying to find a setting to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Lion](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#spotlight), Spotlight menu finally supports dragging items out of it, so you could just update OS X.